# What happens when you add two different types together in C?

Tags: c, types, type-conversion

Given the following code:

```
int foo = 5;
int *foo_ptr = &foo;
return foo_ptr + foo;
```

Will the return type be a pointer or an int? And more generally, what does the compiler do when adding differing type together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, the sum of two different numeric types involves first promoting the arguments so that the types are the same and then adding. The precise algorithm is described in §6.3.1.8 of the C11 standard, "Usual arithmetic conversions", and you can find a summary on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) (the C++ and C standards are the same on this point.) Basically, the algorithm is to choose whichever of the two types is the wider floating point type, or if neither are floating point, the narrowest integer type at least as wide as an `int` which is a superset of both types.

Adding an integer to a pointer `p + i` or `i + p` is the same as `&p[i]` (or `&i[p]`, which is identical). The computation is:

```
&(char*)p + i * (sizeof *p)
```

That's not possible if `p` is `void*`.

Comment: What do you mean by "promoting"? is `p + i` the same as `i + p`?

Comment: @shelvacu: yes, the usual arithmetic conversions are symmetric. The standard takes a whole page to describe them, which seemed excessive. I inserted a link to an online resource and a one sentence summary which skates around some of the obscure corners of the algorithm.